# Textedit : How to replace several different words with the same word?

Tags: regex, replace, plaintext, textedit

I have a txt file that contains unwanted characters such as commas, periods and semicolons, scattered throughout the text.

In textedit (I'm open to other apps), how can I do the equivalent of a simple regex pipe to replace all of these unwanted chars with something else. You know...

Find : ,|.|;

Replace with : < tab >

I known Textedit doesn't do regex, but I haven't even found someone asking this question anywhere.

Comment: Do you have `sed` available?

Comment: What about using some editor that supports regular expressions? Such [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (for windows) or [notepadqq](https://notepadqq.com/s/) (for linux)

Comment: Just as you wrote: `(,|\.|;)` replace with `\t`. Or `[,.;]` -> `\t`.